# Ruby loop via lambda, how to break?

Tags: ruby, loops, lambda

It is possible to create `dead loop` using lambdas in ruby:

```
a = 0
lambda = ->{ a += 1; puts "#{a}"; sleep 1}
loop &lambda
p a
```

**Now I'm seeking for a way how to `break` this kind of loop generated by a `lambda` transferred into block**. Both apparent approaches I used to try dose not finish a loop they just exit out of the lambda, but loop still works:

`break` dose not stop a loop:

```
a = 0
lambda = ->{ a += 1; puts "#{a} break"; sleep 1; break; p "This line will not appears"}
loop &lambda
p a
```

`return` dose not stop a loop too:

```
a = 0
lambda = ->{ a += 1; puts "#{a} return"; sleep 1; return; p "This line will not appears"}
loop &lambda
p a
```

If I use `proc` instead of `lambda` I able to `return` out of a loop, but also I exit out of the program:

```
a = 0
prc_ = Proc.new{a += 1; puts "#{a} proc return"; sleep 1; return; p "This line will not appears"}
loop &prc_
p a
```

The same situations when I use `break` inside `proc`, I just throw away from the program with `LocalJumpError` exception.

```
a = 0
prc_ = Proc.new{a += 1; puts "#{a} proc break"; sleep 1; break; p "This line will not appears"}
loop &prc_
p a
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can raise `StopIteration` exception from the lambda:

```
a = 0
lambda = ->{ a += 1; puts "#{a}"; sleep 1; raise StopIteration if a>10}
loop &lambda
p a
```

[Docs](https://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/loop) says:

> `loop() public`
>   Repeatedly executes the block.
>   If no block is given, an enumerator is returned instead.
>   (...)`StopIteration` raised in the block breaks the loop.

Comment: Great. Thanks for answer, and thanks for markup. So stackoverflow automatically selects code? no need to user 3 backquotes to select code as like as at the github?

Comment: You need to indent the code to have it highlighted: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code. Btw it the answer helps you. pls consider accepting it :)

Comment: `loop` is also commonly used with enumerators. If `e` is enumerator (that is, an instance of the class `Enumerator`), `e.next` or `e.peek` will raise a `StopIteration` exception if `e` is at its last position. `loop` will then handle the exception by breaking out of the loop.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thank you. This is great: 
`a = [1,2,3].each; loop {p a.next}`. I did not know this approach before.